# GridView picture not showing up in fragment, only on Main Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, imageview

I am trying to create an gridview that load url into it. I can get it working in MainActivity but when I paste my code to Gridview. The image isnt showing.

Here is my code on Fragment

```
public static String[] eatFoodyImages = {
        "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//nBNZadXqJSdt05SHLqgT0HuC5Gm.jpg",
        "http://i.imgur.com/C9pBVt7.jpg",
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(getActivity(), eatFoodyImages));

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
}
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment"
android:name="com.example.android.movie.MainFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />
```

Fragment_main_xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.android.movie.MainFragment">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp" />
```

Image_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item_movie"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp">
```

ImageListAdapter:

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private String[] imageUrls;

public ImageListAdapter(Context context, String[] imageUrls) {
    super(context, R.layout.image_view, imageUrls);

    this.context = context;
    this.imageUrls = imageUrls;

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_view, parent, false);
    }

    Picasso
            .with(context)
            .load(imageUrls[position])
            .fit() // will explain later
            .into((ImageView) convertView);

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a bug in the `onCreateView` method.

It should look like that:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    GridView gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(getActivity(), eatFoodyImages));

    return rootView;
}
```